# Серия скриншотов Google карты

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

Пробовал сделать так, чтобы гуглокарта перемещалась между всеми маркерами на карте и делала скриншот этого участка карты. Для теста сделал так, но **естественно** оно не работает как надо:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {               
        for (int i = 0; i < markers.size(); i++)
        {
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(markers.get(i).getLatitude(), markers.get(i).getLongitude()))
                    .zoom(15).build();
            mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

            GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback()
            {
                Bitmap bitmap;

                @Override
                public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot)
                {
                    bitmap = snapshot;
                    try
                    {
                        String time = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
                        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.app.my/files/" + time + ".png"); //just for test
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.e(LogTag.MY_FILTER_ERROR, "Screenshot error", e);
                    }
                }
            };

            mGoogleMap.snapshot(callback);
        }
    }
});
```

Этот код делает необходимое количество скриншотов, но карта не успевает перемещаться между маркерами и прогружаться. Я понимаю, что оно должно работать в отдельном потоке, прошу подсказать, как лучше всего это сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, если кому интересно, сделал так:

```
public void uploadScreenshots()
{
    if (getRootActivity() != null)
    {
        iterator = 0;
        map =...
        sortedKeys =...

        //перемещение к первому маркеру
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(map.get(sortedKeys.get(iterator)).getLatitude(), map.get(sortedKeys.get(iterator)).getLongitude()))
                .zoom(15).build();
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition), 1, new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onFinish()
            {
                iterator++;
                mGoogleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new CallBackLoadMap());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel()
            {
            }
        });

        //далее рекурсивно обходим остальные маркеры
        mGoogleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new CallBackLoadMap());
    }
}

class CallBackLoadMap implements GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback
{
    @Override
    public void onMapLoaded()
    {
        final GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback()
        {
            Bitmap bitmap;

            @Override
            public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot)
            {
                bitmap = snapshot;
                try
                {
                    String time = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.app.my/files/" + time + ".png"); //просто для теста - хардкодить плохо!
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e(LogTag.MY_FILTER_ERROR, "Screenshot error", e);
                }
            }
        };

        mGoogleMap.snapshot(callback);

        if (iterator == sortedKeys.size())
            return;

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(map.get(sortedKeys.get(iterator)).getLatitude(), map.get(sortedKeys.get(iterator)).getLongitude()))
                .zoom(15).build();
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition), 1, new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onFinish()
            {
                iterator++;
                mGoogleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new CallBackLoadMap());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel()
            {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Работает как надо - переход между всему маркерами и создание скриншота после полной загрузки карты в этом месте.